# VC++ 2017 How to convert const wchar_t to WCHAR *

Tags: c++, visual-c++

`VC++` 2017 How to convert const **wchar_t to WCHAR** *

```
WCHAR *vsFilename = L"../Engine/color.vs";
```

> Error E0167

Comment: Your question isn't very clear and that line of code should compile fine on VC++.  Can you show the entire function where that line of code exists and the actual compiler output?

Comment: @selbie With recent [standard conformance improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance) vc++ won't tolerate string literal assignment to pointer to non-const char anymore. As for question itself, declaring it like `WCHAR const *vsFilename` or as `LPCWSTR vsFilename` should fix the error.

Comment: His code still compiles in VC 2017.

Comment: @selbie Conformance behavior is enabled by default for new projects created with VS2017 15.5 causing this line to emit `error C2440`. If you have an older project you need to set `/permissive-` (or `/Zc:strictStrings` for older VS versions) mode manually.

Comment: Ahh... I was using 15.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem when I followed tutorial of DirectX from [http://www.rastertek.com]

But I could fix like this.

```
bool ColorShaderClass::Initialize(ID3D11Device* device, HWND hwnd)
{
    bool result;
    WCHAR vs[] = L"../Engine/color.vs";
    WCHAR ps[] = L"../Engine/color.ps";

    result = InitializeShader(device, hwnd, vs, ps);
....
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting the size of the array explicitly.  Your string is 19 characters long (including the `\0` trailing character), meaning you have an array that has 237 unused characters. Let the compiler figure out what size it needs to have `WCHAR vs[] = L"../Engine/color.vs";`

Comment: @AlexG You are right. I modified it according to your advice. Thank you very much.
'WCHAR vs[256] -> WCHAR vs[]'